# Find all numbers that differ from a single digit 0 with RegEx followed by a specific string

Tags: regex

I get a large compilation output from my IDE when I do a batch build over my complete workspace. For every single projekt it contains a line like this:

```
foo.elf - x error(s), y warning(s)
```

I want to **finde every instance** where the **numer of errors differs from 0**. I do get a slightly prommising result with:

```
[1-9]+ +error
```

but this fails for every instance where the number of errors is evenly divisible by 10 like here

```
foo.elf - 20 error(s), y warning(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like `[1-9][0-9]*(?= error)`

**Example** (Written in python)

```
items =['x error' , '20 error','0 error','15 error','40 error','4 error','456 error' ] 
for item in items:
    print(re.findall(r'[1-9][0-9]*(?= error)',item))
```

**Output**

```
[]
['20']
[]
['15']
['40']
['4']
['456']
```

Comment: [1-9][0-9]*\s+error

Comment: @Alex Thanks. Yes `*` works better. In your code, we get the word `error` also as match. I tried to match only the digits.

Comment: Since this compiler stops anyway after I belive 256 errors this works like a charm and it is easy scalable to the number of digits needed. I am curious though if there is a way to not have to account for the possible number of digits.

Comment: See the latest code. This will work irrespective of number of digits.

Comment: Either of the solutions are fine sine my overall goal is to see with one search that no match was fount so I can be shure everything compiled without errors